# Laravel: Pass Div contents to Form Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

I have used http://complete-ly.appspot.com/ to create a Autocomplete Text Field in my Laravel Form

```
<div class="form-group">
<div id='genre' style='border:1px solid #999;'></div>
<script>
var auto = completely(document.getElementById('genre'), {
    fontSize : '14px',
    fontFamily : 'Arial',
    color:'#933',
});
auto.options = ['Action','Biography','Drama'];
auto.repaint(); 
setTimeout(function() {
auto.input.focus();
},0);
</script>
{{ Form::label('genre', trans('main.genre')) }}
{{ Form::textarea('genre', Input::old('genre'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows'     => 2)) }}
```

I would like to pass the contents **div id='genre'** to **Form::textarea('genre')** so that it may be submitted when the form gets submitted.  I am unsure how to do this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery here (question tagged with jQuery), you can use this submit handler on your form, which gets the contents of the div with id `genre` (would suggest renaming either the div or the textarea to avoid confusion), and then it puts those contents in the textarea with name attribute of `genre`. You will need to replace `form_id` with the id of your form.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
    var genre = $('#genre').html();
    $('textarea[name="genre"]').html(genre);
    return;
});
```